# How does the human spine move during healthy deep breathing?

Tags: breathing, spine

When I googled, I found a lot of questionable sources from various nonscientific sources about human breathing.
Is there any science about what the human spine does during healthy deep breathing? Which parts move forward or backward during inhalation and exhalation?

Comment: There is nothing like "healthy breathing" (or unhealthy to name the contrary). Breathing is a necessity life.

Comment: @Chris Many adults spend their entire lives without ever experiencing the benefits of deep "diaphragmatic" breathing. Beyond increasing the risk of under-oxygenation, shallow breathing puts unnecessary strain on muscles, resulting in chronic problems. Proper breathing can help with stress, anxiety, insomnia, and other conditions.

Comment: @vkehayas That sounds like junk science to me. The benefits of breathing exercises for health have very little to do with the healthiness of particular breathing patterns or oxygenation. Respiration is under homeostatic control and you breathe as much as you need for your current oxygen usage.

Comment: Please forgive me, but I find this a very strange question. Why would one's back movements be the focus of a question about breathing? The back is the structure around which breathing occurs, i.e. the ribcage is attached to the back as are some muscles involved in breathing. The back mostly doesn't *do* anything. That's why normal breathing isn't hampered at all by immobilizing the back (e.g. leaning back hard against a wall.) "Healthy deep breathing" is a myth, unless you're at high risk for pneumonia (e.g. post-operatively).

Comment: What is certain is that your breathing patterns --both inhalation and exhalation-- depend on your emotional state. If you have been conditioned on a certain emotional state, e.g. PTSD, you will breathe differently when triggered. Changing the breathing cycle can change your emotional state as the two go together. Most trained singers, actors, dancers, and athletes --people who do something with their bodies-- will attest that they must master their breathing control to do their work. I agree, though, that the question of the spine's movement during breathing does not appear interesting to me.

Comment: @vkehayas - I wasn't aware that there was any breathing pattern *not* involving inhalation and exhalation. I'll say that *focusing on your breathing* can influence physical and emotional states, but not that the two necessarily go together, e.g. hyperventilation does not usually trigger anxiety, sudden breath holding does not result in pain, etc., whereas the inverse is usually the case.